# A ninja failed related error occurs during the build of the OTA package

Tags: android, linux, android-source, ninja, ota

In the process of building the OTA package, we were following the official document.
(https://source.android.com/docs/core/ota/tools)

```
. build/envsetup.sh && lunch tardis-eng
mkdir dist_output
make dist DIST_DIR=dist_output
```

The configuration settings are in place, and the following error occurs on the third line.

```
environment variables changed value:
   LOG_DIR ("/home/user1/out" -> "/home/user1/dist_output/logs")
Environment variable DIST was set, regenerating...
[ 97% 216/222] build out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/ke
FAILED: out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_configs.txt out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_version.txt
/bin/bash -c "(out/host/linux-x86/bin/unpack_bootimg --boot_img out/target/product/generic_arm64/boot.img --out out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/unpacked_bootimage ) && (build/make/tools/extract_kernel.py --tools lz4:out/host/linux-x86/bin/lz4  --input out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/unpacked_bootimage/kernel   --output-configs out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_configs.txt    --output-release out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/kernel_version.txt )"
boot magic: ANDROID!
kernel_size: 40960
kernel load address: 0x00008000
ramdisk size: 733285
ramdisk load address: 0x02000000
second bootloader size: 0
second bootloader load address: 0x00f00000
kernel tags load address: 0x01e00000
page size: 4096
os version: 7.0.0
os patch level: 2016-08
boot image header version: 0
product name: 
command line args: androidboot.hardware=angler androidboot.console=ttyHSL0 msm_rtb.filter=0x37 ehci-hcd.park=3 lpm_levels.sleep_disabled=1 boot_cpus=0-3 buildvariant=userdebug
additional command line args: 
Cannot extract kernel configs in out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/unpacked_bootimage/kernelCannot extract kernel kernel release in out/target/product/generic_arm64/obj/PACKAGING/check_vintf_all_intermediates/unpacked_bootimage/kernel
16:04:30 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (04:24 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Please help for us.